# Apache CXF Soap1_1 is being sended when using stand-alone jar

Tags: java, soap, cxf

I have some basic stand alone jar application that sends signed SOAP request with attachment. I generated all classes using Apache CXF. 
The issue I'm getting is very strange. When running from Eclipse, everything works just fine but when exporting JAR file, things stop working. 
After digging deep into SOAP infra I figured out that the problem is when I'm running stand alone JAR, SOAP 1.1 is being used (and all messageImpl etc are 1_1Impl in runtime) and this causes the issue, however when running from Eclipse, Soap 1.2 being used and everything works.

I'm running on same Java in both cases.

Here part of code of the port definition.

```
URL wsdl = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("myWsdl.wsdl");
MyService service = new MyService(wsdl);

port = service.getPort(MyServiceInterface.class);
BindingProvider bpPort = (BindingProvider)port;

List<Handler> handlerChain = bpPort.getBinding().getHandlerChain();
handlerChain.add(new SOAPLoggingHandler(true));
bpPort.getBinding().setHandlerChain(handlerChain);

bpPort.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, serverUrl);

InvocationHandler handler = Proxy.getInvocationHandler(port);

BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) handler;
SOAPBinding binding = (SOAPBinding) bp.getBinding();
binding.setMTOMEnabled(true);
```

What can cause such strange behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after doing some deep reverse engineering on the problem, I've figured out that problem was because of

```
URL wsdl = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("myWsdl.wsdl");
```

Obviously when running exported jar, URL will be null and this force CXF to use default values for all SOAP implementation which is SOAP1_1

The easies fix in my case was to externalize wsdl file to filesystem.